# Yellowish Screen on my M509DA asus vivobook 15

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

I am tired of yellowish screen on my asus vivobook 15 (M509DA).
there is no Asus splendid in my laptop but Splendid option is in 'My Asus' App.
Please help me to turn the yellowish screen to natural white.
When I start laptop it has normal screen, but after 2-3 seconds it gets yellowish.
Any Help is highly Appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Did you try updating the video driver? Look also in Settings and type Calibrate Display Color in the Settings Search bar. Calibrate your display.. Also make certain Night Settings are NOT turned ON.